# Cant get this search form to work the way I want it

Tags: php, mysql, search

What i wanted was a "search by category" option next to my search form. My question was, how would I get it to actually search by category? This has eaten about 4 hours and I know some of you could most likely fix this in less than 20 mins. Please help!

heres my search form (with the categories)

```
<br><form action='search.php' method='GET'>
        <font face ='sans serif' size='5'>
    <center>
            <select name='category'>
<option>&nbsp;</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='30'>30</option>
<option value='40'>40</option>
</select><form action="search.php" method="GET">
   <input type='text' size='70' name='search'> 
   <input type='image' value='search' src='images/tickmark.pg'></a><br>

</form>
```

Comment: What's "the way you want it", and how does it look? Screenshots and mockups would help a lot here...

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry i shouldnt have said "the way i want it" i just wanted it to work and search by the categories

Comment: Are you asking for how to position it visually on the page? Or how to get it to actually influence the search results?

Comment: no not the visual aspect of it. how to influence the search results

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't help us answer that question, then. We need to see the server-side code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two `<form>` tags, which is invalid. They cannot be nested within each other. As well, using `<font>` and `<center>` just shows you're stuck in Netscape 3.0 days. You've also go a dangling `</a>` with no matching `<a`> before it.

Try this:

```
<form action="search" method="get">

<div style="text-align: center">

<select name="category"
  <option ...>
  <option ...>
</select>
&nbsp;

<input type="text" size="70" name="search">

<input type="image" value="search" src="images/tickmark.jpg">

</div>

</form>
```